# Unsafe array destructuring of a tuple element with an `any` value using Apollo useQuery

Tags: typescript, eslint, apollo, react-apollo

I am using TypeScript and have a GraphQL query definition called using Apollo's useQuery. Documentation says the call should be typed, but I receive an ESLint error for `data` being an `any` value. How can I fix this?

```
export const listProducerOrgStewards = gql`
    query listProducerOrgStewards($user: String) {
        listProducerOrgStewards(user: $user) {
            ...
    }
`;

const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(listProducerOrgStewards, {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
});
```